# Is there a wasy to emulate super with mixins in typescript?

Tags: typescript, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I am using multiple inheritance via Mixins (using the alternative pattern). Is there a way to get something similar to 'super' with this pattern? Consider the example here

```
abstract class Activatable{
    private activated: boolean = false;
    constructor(){}
    public activate(): void {
        this.activated = true;
        console.log('Activatable activated')
  }
}

class SomethingElse{};

interface ThingParent extends Activatable{}

class ThingParent extends SomethingElse{
    public activate(): void {
        (this as Activatable).activate();
        let addSomeValueHere = true;
        console.log('Thing parent activated')
    }
}

applyMixins(ThingParent, [Activatable]);

class Thing extends ThingParent {
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
    public activate(): void {
        super.activate();
        
        console.log('Thing activated');
    }
}

let thing = new Thing();
thing.activate();



function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, constructors: any[]) {
  constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
        derivedCtor.prototype,
        name,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name) ||
          Object.create(null)
      );
    });
  });
}
```

Thing extends ThingParent which extends via mixins a class called Activatable. When I call activate on Thing, I want to call activate on ThingParent and Activatable too, but it is only called on Activatable.

If I change the name of the function on ThingParent I can call that function directly, but ThingParent doesn't have access to Activatable via super (because it extends SomethingElse). I would then have to call both super.activate() and this.thingParentActivate() from thing.activate() so it's a pattern I would like to avoid if possible.

Is there an alternative?

(Link to code on typescript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAggvAlgN2AlGQFMBvAWACgFaEAHKfQkhOCZiEgEwC4EQAe0GlgAOwQBeBADNgyMCQDc1OkkFjIUAK7xBUABQBKMgF9VdetpDIcsNrgJdj-PIJzcElGmroQAFjhgAHTsnDxSCNDayha+6poiJMHIggDmBgDk2BxOxKxhTjyZRhbmVOXUKGgYAMqCALYkAThiaQCiCuSmKlTUrVxQcrCsACqBbQAKwFAkYogkAB5cYtwYOZz5ZtRVqOgI461p07PzCEsrawj1TS1tnYrealY2dg65LC4Ibh5ecb4GFoYNBYRyEfJGUJg5xGXrxWikRDAbjcG4kABq8hiAAkSLNItFYj54rANGAkil0llDm0GDM5kjocVSsSEOVKlRqvsaWlzss5lceScGX9WaTNNE9IYTP81GBtPQ8cZ-uVntZbPZCp8jK53J4nvD5YqoFCPjC4fDZXRxeTSJSMpkee9wtwShbaOydlRgPR6MgAJ4AWRwi1aYAMQvp8wANAgANobPI2EgAXVhXuoiKiE150jEJAA7gcc8Zenc0qbwqWM30qDJtGJcBo2L6A8HQ5oDNw8fgeABhCD6fjif2xm2SwdQMDDsT+uNp0W0cc6KUhGT6dpwfwGAwgNAkAf6IxSAB8i7oAHkQAArEjwYJpZoXgtiSZQQTGiD+gBywCa4b3RRDxNRhBEHL9FUhdcoE3WBtwMMQ-xIY9JDPA01CvW9727GRWhIN8PzxL8DCtWhuyYPB+0nYJQPA-1FWjUiEEQppGNZDCbzvCAHyfF8CM-f0ABESDAWAmHoSdd33YCaPfOiGOYpDjwAH2UpjaEwrjgjEkhPjEbRkGQFl4nTVlTFMj1TNMIA)

Comment: I don't really understand exactly what you're asking for. How could we programmatically delegate a single super method call to *multiple* methods? How do we know which one should be called first or how to compose their return values? It's hard for me to even imagine a version of your example code that wouldn't end up in an infinite loop. `this as Activatable` has no runtime effect, and therefore if you *could* call the `ThingParent` `activate()` it would end up calling itself. Blecch. Can you articulate a specific methodology for how such multi inheritance should actually work?

Comment: You say you could make `thingParentActivate()`... could you show that? If I try this it just gives me an infinite loop.

Comment: Hey jcalz, `this as Activatable` was just there to illustrate how I would like it to work. The infinite loop is removed by stopping ThingParent from calling Activatable.activate(), which kind of defeats the point: shorturl.at/djwz5. I see what you mean abot composing return values though.

Comment: shorturl.at/djwz5 goes nowhere useful for me.  Could you [edit] the code in your question to demonstrate how you intend for this to work?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. The way I would like it to work is like multiple inheritance in C++... I want a class to inherit from two or more others, so that when I call super.methodName() it goes through each of the super classes in order and calls the apprpriate method if it exists. That way I can override methods from any of the parent classes.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it... if the superclasses both contain the method, which one is called? Does it call both?  In what order? What happens with the return type?  You say "like multiple inheritance in C++", but in C++ you have to fully qualify the superclass explicitly, there's no "`super`", is there?  Can you point me to documentation that shows how this works in C++?

Comment: This is the c++ version of what I would like to achive: https://onecompiler.com/cpp/3y9rrp4zv

Comment: Output:

Activatable activated.
Thing parent activated.
Thing activated.
Called a function on SomethingElse base class.

Comment: It looks like MSDN does provide a __super keyword - though this is new to me too: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/super?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170. But the parent scope resolution operator does much the same. Base::activate() will call activate on the parent class called Base, which is where my `(this as Activatable).activate();` came from.

Comment: Well, as we know, JS doesn't have the same kind of class model that C++ does.  JS uses prototypical inheritance.  So you can get the behavior you're talking about like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLqPeW), perhaps?  Does that meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Oh wow, so simple :facepalm: yes that does exactly what I was after. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, JavaScript classes don't support multiple inheritance, so you need to do something to simulate it if you want to get that effect.  [Mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html) are one way to do this, but they don't really support having conflicting method names.  If you have conflicting method names then mixins will end up clobbering all but one of them, which is not what you want.

If you want to call a particular "superclass"'s method on the "subclass"'s instance, you can do so directly with the [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) with the instance as the `this` arg.  Instead of `Activatable::activate()`, you call `Activatable.prototype.activate.call(this);`.

Let's try it out:

```
interface ThingParent extends Activatable { }
class ThingParent extends SomethingElse {
    public activate(): void {
        Activatable.prototype.activate.call(this);
        let addSomeValueHere = true;
        console.log('Thing parent activated')
    }
}

class Thing extends ThingParent {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    public activate(): void {
        ThingParent.prototype.activate.call(this);
        console.log('Thing activated');
    }
}

let thing = new Thing();
thing.activate();
// [LOG]: "Activatable activated" 
// [LOG]: "Thing parent activated" 
// [LOG]: "Thing activated"
```

That compiles okay and produces the output you expect.

---

In more complex scenarios you may decide you need to do a combination of mixins and direct method `call`s.  Or some other approach.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAggvAlgN2AlGQFMEBvAWACgE6EAHKfQsuCFiEgEwC4EQAe0GlgAOwQBeBADNgyMCQDcNekkFjIUAK7xBUABQBKCggC+q+g20hkOWAnacSx-nkE5uFS2roQAFjhgAHROBFxe0tDayj6+sBpgIiTByIIA5gYA5Ngc4cRsuOE8WUZxFtQVNChoGADKggC2JAE4YukAogpk5OYq1DRtXFBysGQAKoHtAArAUCRiiCQAHlxi3Bi5nAWmFTXoCJNt6bPziwgraxsIDc2t7V2K3rRWNnYOYayuCO6ez770Lb5WwpJiCCDggCeDBSny4wVg8mQBlaYCM-QBdFIiGA3G4txIADV5DEABIkeZSBDRWIvAEJTTJVIZbJHdqMOYLHFFVjcUrlGhVaj7DBs9IXVYLa5i05c-70BlaXQQwwmKh03xgbQw1UCjXWWz2Rw8rjfX5edWYw5TE6cxbBMEQiDQ2EmlKI5DI1HouJqRVMtKZLJi415XmlDH0CpC7HUm1UsQkADu1uOxn693SoTd6ZoQA)